# Eclipelink @ElementCollection remove all on merge

Tags: eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have this mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
class Customer {

   @Id
   @Column(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
   Long id;

   ...

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="CUSTOMER_ADDRESS", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID"))
   List<CustomerAddress> addresses;

}

@Embeddable
class CustomerAddress {

   String street;
   String zip;
   String ...
   String ...
   ...
}
```

I have two saved addresses for customer ID : 1. If i update this customer, having a single address on, Eclipselink tries deletes the missing address row using all CustomerAddress fields on DELETE where statement:

```
DELETE FROM CUSTOMER_ADDRESS WHERE STREET = ?, ..., ZIP = ?, ..., CUSTOMER_ID = ?
```

The issue is i may have accents and other data that prevents the WHERE statement to match the row using all fields. Is there anyway to force Eclipselink to delete all user addresses and insert again?

```
DELETE FROM CUSTOMER_ADDRES WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = ?
INSERT ALL FROM COLLECTION
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing the collection,  flushing, and then re-adding the CustomerAddress?  Why would accents or other data prevent deletion - what is in the object should match what is in the row.

Comment: Actually i am reciving the updated entity from a Rest services and by the time i call em.merge this is still an unmanaged reference. So i am not really loading it from the database.

Comment: Merge will load the data so that it can merge your instance into it.  It has no way of knowing what to remove otherwise.

Comment: So my question stands. How could i force it to delete all data and create the dataset again? As far as i know, this is what Hibernate does by default. Thank you mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to accomplish what i wanted. It seems Hibernate has the behavior i expect.

Changed ElementCollection to OneToMany and changed the model to have an ID under CustomerAddress.